# Webview doesn't take the full height

Tags: android, webview

I am using Navigation Drawer with TabLayout. I have a fragment in which is WebView but the webview doesn't take in full height when running. I tried changing webview / relative layout height but didn't work . In the designer the height fits perfectly with the device on screen navigation buttons.

My xml code

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/website_detail_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </WebView>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:indeterminate="false"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

My Java Code

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {

    public WebView webView;
    public ProgressBar progressBar;

    public Tab1Fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);


    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//

         progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
      //  String url = "http://www.carsaleindiaofficial.com/?m=1";
        webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.website_detail_1);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        //view.loadUrl(url);
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.yahoo.com");
        // view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/web.html");


    }

    public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            //view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.i("pageFinished", "yesss");
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }


    }
}
```

Result
[image]

Comment: You should find out the space is on WebView or web page.

Comment: I tried different webpage all have that space at the bottom. The space is definitely on WebView.

Comment: Did you try different webpage from different website?

Comment: yes. the height fits perfectly on devices with on screen buttons. To my understanding webview is not compensating the height of appbar or on screen buttons.

Comment: try a frame layout instead of relative. see if that helps

Comment: Can you show the layout of activity as well where you are inflating the fragment. It seems you have some view in you activity layout that is not allowing the fragment to occupy full height

Comment: Same problem here... no solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue lay with viewpager height.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set the progress bar to VISIBILITY GONE.

INVISIBLE still reserves the space.

Comment: tried both the answers . Not working the blank space is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    <activity
        android:name="YourActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
```